# Why am i getting NullPointerException for a CheckedTextView when i click a row after scrolling in ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, onitemclicklistener

I have a ListView in my activity. Following is the way i am setting an OnCLickListener on rows of the ListView

```
 listview.setAdapter(new RowsArrayAdapter(this, rows));

 listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         CheckedTextView ctv = (CheckedTextView) lv.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.row_checkbox);
         ctv.setChecked(true);

 });
```

getView() method for RowsArrayAdapter is following:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

         LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

         View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);

         CheckedTextView row = (CheckedTextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_checkbox);
         row.setText(values[position].getRow_no());

         return rowView;
}
```

It works fine for first 8 rows. I checked the array rows length. Its 16 which is right. But when i scroll down and click on some row for example row 12 then it gives me NullPointerException. Any idea why is that and how can i fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show getView method in RowsArrayAdapter

Comment: code added. please have a look

Answer (score 2):

This produces null:

```
CheckedTextView ctv = (CheckedTextView) lv.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.row_checkbox);
ctv.setChecked(true);
```

But this does not:

```
CheckedTextView ctv = (CheckedTextView)  lv.getAdapter().getView(position, null,  lv).findViewById(R.id.row_checkbox);
ctv.setChecked(true);
```

Please try this

Comment: It will not work, because adapter will create a new view every time getView is called. It will not change anything on the screen, because you will just create new view, change their state and attach to view hierarchy on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You should use.

```
 CheckedTextView ctv = (CheckedTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_checkbox);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not store state in row view itself. Even if you will be able to find the proper row and set a checkbox to checked state, you will have a problem when you will scroll back. To solve this I recommend you to add checked flag in your model and populate checked state in getView method of your adapter. In onClick listener, you will need to modify your model and notifyDataSetChanged on your adapter.

You should not inflate the same view every time in getView method otherwise you will have a very bad performance. You should inflate it only if convertView == null, otherwise just reuse convert view.

I highly recommend you to use RecyclerView instead of listview as it forces to use ViewHolder pattern. Read more here: https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder